# Spring: Generic class with autowired dependencies

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, dependency-injection

I have a standard Spring Boot MVC app with many entities and corresponding repositories and services. There's a lot of infrastructure shared among the components so I would like to abstract that away to generic classes. The way I'm currently trying to achieve that is this (showing just the skeleton to convey the idea):

```kotlin
interface AbstractRepository<T> {
    fun findById(entityId: Long): T 
}

abstract class AbstractEntityService<T>(
  private val entityRepository: AbstractRepository<T>,
) {

  fun getEntity(entityId: Long): T = entityRepository.findById(entityId)
}

@Repository
interface MyRepository : AbstractRepository<MyEntity>

@Service
class MyEntityService(
  myRepository: MyRepository,
  /* some other dependencies */
) : AbstractEntityService<MyEntity>(myRepository) {
  /* some additional methods */
}
```

This seems to work, i.e. I can instantiate (or autowire) `MyEntityService`. Note, however, that I have to pass `MyRepository` explicitly to the constructor instead of letting Spring autowire it. That isn't possible because of runtime type erasure. But so far it doesn't bother me much.

Problems arise when I want to add some logic to `AbstractEntityService` which requires some other beans, i.e. something like this

```kotlin
@Service
abstract class AbstractEntityService<T>(
  private val entityRepository: AbstractRepository<T>,
) {
  
  @Autowired
  private lateinit var otherService: OtherService

  fun getEntity(entityId: Long): T

  fun commonMethodUsingOtherService(): T
}
```

But now I have a problem because in order to autowire `OtherService` I had to make my abstract service a Spring component (`@Service`) which has an unwanted side effect of Spring trying to inject `AbstractRepository<T>` declared in my constructor. And because of the above mentioned type erasure it finds lots of beans of `AbstractRepository` type and fails.

**My question**: How can I convince Spring to not inject a bean into my `AbstractEntityService` constructor?

**Related question**: Is there a technically different solution to my problem (mentioned in the first paragraph) which avoids possible framework restrictions/shortcomings? I.e. not using inheritance, structuring my code differently etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this

```
@Service
abstract class AbstractEntityService<T>(
  private val entityRepository: AbstractRepository<T>,
) {
  
  @Autowired
  private lateinit var otherService: OtherService

  fun getEntity(entityId: Long): T

  fun commonMethodUsingOtherService(): T
}
```

actually works, in spite of what OP (me) claimed in the issue. Apparently, Spring supports autowiring in abstract classes. Moreover, `@Service` annotation (or generally `@Component`) is understandably ignored by Spring, so it doesn't try to inject `AbstractRepository<T>` into the constructor. On the other hand, Spring can inject it if declared explicitly because it [supports generics as bean qualifiers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-generics-as-qualifiers):

```
abstract class AbstractEntityService<T> {
  
  @Autowired
  private lateinit var otherService: OtherService

  @Autowired
  private lateinit var entityRepository: AbstractRepository<T>
}
```

I really don't know what I was thinking when I posted this issue :-) Perhaps, I got confused by errors emitted by IDE which apparently is not so smart and cannot perform the generic type bean resolution, so it complains `Could not autowire. No beans of 'AbstractRepository<T>' type found.`

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be solved by replacing the field injection of `AbstractEntityService` with constructor injection, and removing the `@Service` annotation:

```kotlin
abstract class AbstractEntityService<T>(
    private val entityRepository: AbstractRepository<T>,
    private val otherService: OtherService,
) {
    ...
}
```

Now, if this class wasn't abstract, its dependencies could be injected by Spring at least as good as in the definition where `otherService` is a field. But this definition is better in the way that you can now also pass the dependency into this class from your subclass like this:

```kotlin
@Service
class MyEntityService(
    myRepository: MyRepository,
    otherService: OtherService,
    /* some other dependencies */
) : AbstractEntityService<MyEntity>(myRepository, otherService) {
    /* some additional methods */
}
```

I'm not quite sure what you mean why `MyRepository` cannot be autowired because of type erasure, I guess there are some details missing in the question.

If the problem is that you have different components of type `MyRepository` in your application context, you could annotate one of them with `@Primary` which makes Spring to choose that component whenever it has to autowire a single candidate.

Another way could be to give your bean a name and then qualify the dependency in your `MyEntityService`:

```kotlin
@Repository("myrepo")
open class MyRepository : AbstractRepository<MyEntity> {
   ...
}

@Service
class MyEntityService(
    @Qualifier("myrepo")
    myRepository: AbstractRepository<MyEntity>,
    otherService: OtherService,
    /* some other dependencies */
) : AbstractEntityService<MyEntity>(myRepository, otherService) {
    /* some additional methods */
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I should have stated from the beginning that I know about this solution and find it suboptimal because (as I have said) I have "many entities and corresponding repositories and services". So I have `MyEntity1`, `MyEntity2` etc., all with corresponding repos `MyRepository1`, `MyRepository2`, ... and services `MyEntityService1`, `MyEntityService2`... `OtherService` is just an implementation detail of `AbstractEntityService` so its subclasses shouldn't ideally know about that otherwise we are breaking the separation of concerns principle.

Comment: E.g. what if `AbstractEntityService` needs other "private" dependency in the future? Then we have to modify all subclass services to construct that dependency and pass it to the superclass, even if they have no direct use for it. But I understand that there's probably no better solution given the limitations of Spring and JVM (see below).

Comment: Regarding "MyRepository cannot be autowired because of type erasure" I meant this: In an ideal world where generic type parameters are retained in runtime I can imagine that I would define `AbstractEntityService` with no-arg constructor and autowired  `entityRepository` and `otherService` fields. This would lead to correct separation of concerns IMO. Unfortunately, that isn't possible because Spring can't autowire `AbstractRepository<T>` because the concrete `T` is erased at runtime.